# Giving remote access to files for only a single directory on a Linux server

Tags: linux, ssh, ftp, network-shares, samba

I need to give a user named "Bert" access to one directory (`/var/www/application/thisDirectory/`) on my Linux server.

Initially, I tried to use FTP (actually SSH).

My first thought was to chroot Bert and make his home `/var/www/application/thisDirectory/`.  Problem is this requires `/var/www/application/` to be owned and only available to root which is not acceptable.

I then changed Bert's home directory to `/home/Bert/`.  Next, I put a symbolic link in Bert's home directory and pointed to `/var/www/application/thisDirectory`, but I don't believe this was permitted because Bert was chroot'd and is considered a security risk, and I couldn't get it to work.  Any thoughts how it can work?

Next, leaving Bert's home directory as `/home/Bert/`, I moved `/var/www/application/thisDirectory` to `/home/Bert/thisDirectory/`, and added symbolic link `/var/www/application/thisDirectory/` to point to `/home/Bert/thisDirectory/`.  While this technically worked, it caused havoc with my Git version control, and I switched back.

If I can't get this working, I suppose I could look into Samba, but would rather not.

Thank you

Comment: Why not plain FTP? It will be easy to keep the user limited to one directory that way.

Comment: Everyone says no to FTP, but I suppose it will be okay.  Is the only risk someone could get Bert's username and password, and have access to '/var/www/application/thisDirectory/`?  I am okay with this.  How would I do so?

Comment: Hosting providers use FTP. As long as your FTP server is properly patched and updated, I don't see any other risk. And, unless you force Bert to use a PGP key, someone could get his username and password, and login using SSH too.

Comment: @drk.com.ar.  I meant FTP is not encrypted and someone could sniff the username and password.  That being said, this is okay.  How do I limit FTP access on only one directory?  Thanks

Comment: Oh, sniffing. You're right, but someone could stealth then using a key logger too. Of course, SSH is better than FTP. But in this case I think you are going to be better with FTP. "chrooting" users in FTP is different for every FTP server software. Which one are you using?

Comment: The server is Centos 6.5.  I have ftp and vsftp currently installed via Yum, and could of course install others as well.

Comment: Check " /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf" for "chroot_list_enable" option and "/etc/vsftpd/chroot_list" for chrooted users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used this way and i can tell it works,

in your /etc/ssh/sshd_config, after the change reload the sshd service

```
Match User bert
ChrootDirectory /home/%u
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

add the user

```
useradd -m -s /bin/false bert
passwd bert
```

permission for sftp

```
chown root:root /home/bert
```

create the directory for bert user under my the root of my webserver:

```
mkdir /srv/www/htdocs/bertdir
chown bert:wwwrun /srv/www/htdocs/bertdir
```

Create the mountpoint under home of bert user for mount the directory:

```
mkdir /home/bert/www
```

Now we mount the directory

```
mount --bind /srv/www/htdocs/bertdir/ /home/bert/www/
```

Now i used my sftp service:

```
sftp> ls
bin          public_html  www
```

Now i upload the /etc/passwd

```
sftp> put /etc/passwd
Uploading /etc/passwd to /www/passwd
```

Comment: I've tried something similar.  Instead of `Match User bert`, I used `Match Group public` where Bert belongs to group "public".  Should be the same, right?  My only concern is whether this will mess with Git when you mount `/srv/www/htdocs/bertdir/` on `/home/bert/www/`.  Git is currently tracking all files under `/srv/www/` (actually `/var/www/` for my configuration).  Should I have any concerns?  Thank you

Comment: I can't tell you nothing about git because i don't use it now, try and let me know

Comment: I will give it a try, and let you know how it works out.  I had problems doing something similar, but not mounting the directory, but instead using a symbolic link.  After thinking about it, I think it will be okay mounting it since Git won't know the difference.  PS.  Git is great.  Just recently started using it, and wonder how I got this far without it.

Comment: Worked great.  The key is mounting and not using a symbolic link.